# cocoa tabView Name

Tags: cocoa, tabview

I want to get the tabView name programatically. What is the property to do this?

I have tried:

[tabView name];
[tabView value];

but none of these seem to do the trick.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think tab views have names… do you mean you want the title of the currently selected tab?

Comment: Yes that would work as well... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the title of the currently selected tab in an `NSTabView`, you could do this:

```
NSString *title = [[myTabView selectedTabViewItem] label];
```